# Question about sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let's say we have two independent discrete random variables, $X=\left\{ 0,1\right\}$ and $Y=\left\{ 2,3\right\}$.

What does it mean to sum these two variable? In other words: $S=Y+X=?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the experience, $X$ and $Y$ may take values $0,1$ and $2,3$ respectively. When you do it many times, you may get four results for their sum $S$ : $0+2$, $0+3$, $1+2$ and $1+3$. Hence each time you do the experience, $S$ takes a number in $\{2,3,4\}$ with a certain probability that depends on the distributions of $X$ and $Y$. So $S$ is a random variable.

Comment: OK. I understood the idea but I do not understand the meaning of the summation of independent random variables in the Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: @DavideLaVardera Well, in the Central Limit Theorem we let $n\to\infty$ for a sum of $n$ random variables, but that's the same logic. Anyway, formally, random variables are just functions. Given a random experience with set of outcomes $\Omega$, a random variable $X$ is a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$. That is, to each outcome we assign a value for $X$. Then if $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are $n$ random variables, their sum $S$ is just the sum of $n$ functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Let's say that I take a sample of size n from a certain population: in the TLC, are the random variables the samples itself (the values assigned to the outcomes) or the random variables are the single outcomes of the sample ($X_n$ is the n-th member of the sample)? In other words n is the sample size or the number of samples? Is there any difference between the two procedures?